# The name 'Log' does not exist in the current context in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am totally beginner to Xamarin Mobile development. I am learning it from Xamarin Website. I am doing a sample provided on the same website. [activity_lifecycle/saving_state_walkthrough](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/activity_lifecycle/saving_state_walkthrough/).

```
protected override void OnSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)
{
  outState.PutInt ("click_count", _counter);
  Log.Debug(GetType().FullName, "Saving instance state");

  base.OnSaveInstanceState (outState);
}
```

when i build the Project it trows me error on **Log.Debug**, that **Log.Debug does not exists in Current Context.**

i don't know to how to resolve this, can any body help me. is there any additional namespace or reference i need to add to the project. Please help me.

Comment: My recommendation to you is that you get a good book or online tutorial on Android development. It is critical that you have a working knowledge of Android, as Xamarin is simply a C# layer over the base Java system. With that, you would have known that a Java imports is equivalent to C# using. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the Solution:

We just need to add

```
using Android.Util;
```

namespace it will work.

Thanks for your time have a good day.